# MySQL select inner join matches less rows than expected

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

table_products  45000 rows (for filter_id = 5, 9000 rows)

```
 product_id |  model  | filter_id
 --------------------------------
    1        | 040853 | 5
    1        | 015397 | 5
    4        | 001127 | 5
    5        | 008735 | 5
    5        | 009680 | 5
```

table_vendor 4500 rows

```
    sku  |stock | price
 --------------------------------
  040853 | 12  | 12.0
  015397 | 4   | 22.9
  009680 | 144 | 13.5
  009772 | 1   | 11.8
  007627 | 150 | 44.8
```

and I am using the following mysql query to find the products where table_products.filter_id = 5 
and table_vendor.stock > 2  :

```
 Select * 
   from table_products AS pro
   JOIN table_vendor  AS vend 
    ON pro.model = vend.sku
  where pro.filter_id = 5
    and vend.stock > 2
```

I have no duplicate values in both tables,
but the query matches fewer products than expected.
there are products that satisfy the requirements that are not matched.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This sku column is varchar right? and Can you comment here few records which are expected as part of output but didn't come?

Comment: yes both table_vendor.sku and table_products.model are varchar(64). i found that the select is not mathing all products by exporting to csv and finding the duplicate table_products.model = table_vendor.sku via Excel.    The  table_products.model  = 030664 that also resides in  table_vendor as  030664 | 50 | 25.3900, is not matched for example

Comment: Width provided data it works just fine: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dGpet15fuKj8hd46EtfZH9/0

Comment: It works with data in your comment also; https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dGpet15fuKj8hd46EtfZH9/1

Comment: Never use `SELECT *`